# How to validate Generalized Least Square model for longitudinal response

Tags: regression, panel-data, validation, regression-strategies

I have a dataset with body weights before and in the follow-up visits after surgery, for a group of patients with obesity. Our goal is to fit a model to predict weight loss throughout the follow-up.
Frank Harrell's *Regression Modelling Strategies* includes a chapter on modelling this kind of data, with a GLS approach, and using the rms package. Although validation and bootstrap are extensively discussed in the book, they are not clearly applied to GLS models.
Any suggestion on how to validate these models with bootstrapping methods?

Answer (score 0):

If you want more information about gls procedures, I suggest to read Pinheiro and Bates, 1999 or 2002. The authors developed the package `nlme` and have a function called `gls` and `gnls` for linear and non-linear models, respectively.